# Root Cname - WHM?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to configure my DNS on my VPS through WHM.
I need like to add two CNAME records and no A records. I've read that this is possible and it works... even though apparently it violates the RFC.

```
* CNAME apps.otherdomain.com
domainname.com CNAME otherdomain.com
```

However, WHM does not seem to want to do this. Is it just that WHM doesn't want to do this? Can I do this if I dig into bind?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a CNAME as the root of your zone, since it also has an SOA record, and a CNAME can't co-exist with any other type of record.

Comment: From what I understand.... it's possible... http://serverfault.com/questions/55528/set-root-domain-record-to-be-a-cname

Comment: The only thing I can assume is that either they've hacked their namesever, or they're putting the CNAME in the parent zone, and not delegating it at all. The fact that the query returned only a CNAME would tend to confirm my thoery.

Comment: I don't need to delegate it at all.... would it be possible then?

Comment: If it's not being delegated to you either (i.e. it doesn't need an SOA/NS record) then yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to use any of it's sub domains, it appears it would be possible to do something similar with DNAME
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=19798