# Why can't a domain's root be a CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I've just read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/62527/how-to-create-a-cname-for-a-domains-root-name) which essentially says that when I set up DNS for example.com, the root record can't be a CNAME, it has to be an A record.

My question is, why?

I'm sure the clever people who designed DNS didn't make arbitary restrictions for no reason, but I don't see what we gain by requring root domains to be A records. I would love to just point my example.com domain to someserver.somewebhost.example and forget about it, but I can't.

Please enlighten me, billpg.

Comment: Odd that my question, asked in 2010, has now been marked as a duplicate of a question asked in 2014. Maybe I should tag that one as a duplicate of this instead. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firstly, the underlying reason is not that you must use an A record, but that you cannot use a CNAME record because those cannot coexist with other normal resource record types.

The reason for *that* restriction is in §3.6.2 of RFC 1034:

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no
>   other data should be present; this
>   ensures that the data for a canonical
>   name and its aliases cannot be
>   different.  This rule also insures
>   that a cached CNAME can be used
>   without checking with an authoritative
>   server for other RR types.

As the root of a (delegated) domain must have an SOA and NS records the rule above kicks in, preventing use of CNAMEs too.

Comment: The restriction is still annoying, but at least now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Well it's not that the root of a domain can't be a `CNAME` - It's that a `CNAME` cannot coexist with other record types for the same domain.

Simply put, it would make no sense for a domain with a `CNAME` to have any other record type, because the `CNAME` would ensure that they would never be seen or read.

Let's say we did try to give `example.net` both a `CNAME` (pointing to host.example.*com*) and an `A` record (pointing to some other IP address).

1. First, the client would request an `A` record from `example.net` from example.net's nameservers.
2. example.net's nameservers would inform us that we need to follow a `CNAME` record in order to proceed.  So we do.  The `CNAME` points to `host.example.com`.
3. The client would request an `A` record from `host.example.com`'s nameservers.

Notice how we never got the chance to read an `A` record, or any other record type, from example.net?  The `CNAME` takes precedence.