# Is there a better way to redirect my client's domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, a-record

I serve multiple websites for my clients on one server. During development I simply make a subdomain on my own domain. Example `client.mydomain.example`.
Often my customers already have a domain and email with another provider. 
I do not want to host email for my clients.

**I have tried three different ways of setting up DNS:**

1. Make an HTTP redirect from `clientdomain.example` to `www.clientdomain.example` and then a CNAME record for `www.clientdomain.exmple` to point to temporary subdomain on my server `client.mydomain.example`.
2. Have an A record from `(*.)clientdomain.tld` to my server IP, but leaving MX and such to point to their current email-host.
3. Set up my own nameservers and use those for my client's domain. Then setup the same way as 2.

As far as I can see there are pros and cons with all three:

1. **Pros:** Convenient. I can change the IP address on my server, move to another serverpark, set up failsafe, load balancing and so on.
   **Cons:** I force my clients to use `www`, and if they already have a site on `non-www` they might suffer SEO-vise(?). Also the extra
   CNAME record is bad for page speed.
2. **Pros:** No SEO or page-speed issues. Easy setup.
   **Cons:** If I need to change IP, I need to make DNS changes for ALL my client sites.
3. **Pros:** No SEO or page-speed issues. If I need to change server, I can do this for all my client sites at once, since DNS settings is conveniently setup on my own name servers.
   **Cons:** I need to run my own name servers. I also have to set up MX records and possibly other DNS records for my customers.

My preferred way right now is 1. since I think the pros outweighs the cons for most of my cases.

Are there any other way to redirect from a domain to a server without specifying the IP-address?

Clarification: Solution 1 works for me, but it is slower because of the two steps before coming to the final A record. Ideally I would want to point both `non-www` and `www` to my server domain, but as far as I know, this is not possible with a CNAME record, right?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you please try editing your post to make it clear the problem you're trying to solve. DNS is usually pretty simple.

Comment: Why would you redirect anyone to your development server at all? Those should only be accessible by people who develop the website, which should at least be smart enough to type in a correct url themselves...

Comment: @tim I added clarification

Comment: I still don't understand the question. You've said you've tried three ways of doing something, but haven't said what that something is. Are you trying to set up production DNS to point at your sever? Development subdomain? Is it another server? Really unclear.

Comment: The CNAME, as all other DNS related stuff will be cached and have mostly no influence on the global performance of your website.

Comment: @OnklMaps I have edited your post to try being it more tight on the terminology used. Redirection only happens on the HTTP level, it has no meaning in DNS, where A/AAAA/CNAME records can be used to map a given hostname to some IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice, that a `CNAME` is not a HTTP redirect at all.

- Only redirect here is from the `example.com` to `www.example.com` and it can be made permanent. The extra `CNAME` is on DNS level and will be cached, so it doesn't really affect the site performance nor speed at all.
- Your web server needs to be aware of the client domain despite who's hosting the DNS.

That's why I'd prefer your case #1, with a better understanding:

1. Guide your client to add `www.example.com. CNAME client.example.net.` to be able to change the IP address on your own, if necessary.
2. Advise how to make a redirect from non-www to www on their current web server.
3. Bind the actual domain name to your `client.example.net` in your webserver's configuration.

With the case #3 you won't just end up technically hosting DNS servers, but also be responsible of doing updates whenever a client needs a new third party record.

Comment: What about the non-www to www, that's a HTTP redirect, right? So that can possibly affect performance some milliseconds? Also, this "www-redirect" that most domain providers have, that is based on some rewrite rule in a .htaccess file?

Answer (score -1):

So if I understood correctly what you want to do is to have the ability after the development phase to simply point a cname to your server (client.mydomain.tld) and handle the rest on your own server.

What I tried on my Setup right now with Cloudflare for managing my DNS entrys is to just put two cname records one www.client.tld and one client.tld.
After that you can Handle the request on your Server and just rewrite the URL to the specific needs.

I would also choose your option number one since it's the easiest to handle.

And I also found some Information about the use of CNAME records here:
[Should CNAME Be Used For Subdomains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/181927/should-cname-be-used-for-subdomains)

Comment: You understood correctly. But how did you cname from client.tld? I thought that was not possible?

Comment: @OnklMaps you are right you can not put a CNAME at apex of a zone, since it already has at least NS records there, and CNAME can not cohabit with any other record types.