# How to Redirect the Root of this Domain

Tags: apache-2.4, redirection

I have created a launchrock.com page and I am directing signup.mydomain.com there using a CNAME record in the DNS.  That works fine however now I want to direct root traffic there too, i.e. mydomain.com.  How do I go about this?

Launchrock give instructions to change the IP address of the A record, however I don't want to do this since I have other subdomains in use, including beta.mydomain.com.  (These subdomains need to continue operating as they currently do).

How do I do this?  I'm not sure whether it's a DNS change or an Apache change.

I am using a recent version of Apache on Ubuntu on AWS EC2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't a domain's root be a CNAME?](http://serverfault.com/questions/170194/why-cant-a-domains-root-be-a-cname)

Comment: @MadHatter, this doesn't help.  I need to be able to redirect the root somehow.  I don't care whether CNAME is involved or not...

Comment: You already know how to do this: with an A record.  You can't do it with a CNAME.  There are no other options.

Comment: Surely that can't be the case.  What about using mod_rewrite in Apache?

Comment: @MadHatter, see answer below...

Comment: That presumably means that **you've already got an A record defined for mydomain.com, and a webserver running at that address**.  You kind of omitted to mention those details!  But you are right that given that infrastructure, you can do this without any DNS changes.

Comment: @MadHatter If you read the second paragraph of my question you will get the full picture.

Comment: I did; it makes no mention of an existing web server at the current A record for `mydomain.com`.  However, I'm glad you've found a solution that works for you; you should probably accept your answer when the site permits it (that may take a day or two).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the answer was simply to put a redirect command in the virtual host setup for the root host.

```
Redirect / http://signup.mydomain.com/
```