# How to use CNAME to external hosts on local DNS Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, internal-dns

I have a domain `mydomain.com` and I'm using an external DNS Server to resolve some names like `www.mydomain.com` and `webmail.mydomain.com` on Internet.

Now, I need to create a rule, only on my LAN, to resolve `newserver.mydomain.com` to `newserver.cloudapp.net` (a new server hosted at Azure).

At first I tought, "I can create a CNAME entry on my local DNS Server and the job is done!" but to do it I had to create another zone to resolve `*.mydomain.com` and all went wrong. My DNS server was able to resolve `newserver.mydomain.com` but all other URLs were unavailable... of course, my local DNS server became "authoritative" for that domain.

I'm using Windows Server 2012, and I only want to configure my DNS Server to do this:

Resolve this entry:

`newserver.mydomain.com CNAME newserver.cloudapp.net`

and

`*.mydomain.com` still resolving on external DNS Server.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: If we're talking about resolving on one host only: Why not use your hosts file for this? :)

Comment: We need resolve this name from any host in our LAN... thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to create an internal zone `example.com` which overrides the whole domain, create an internal zone for a subdomain `newserver.example.com` authoritative for `*.newserver.example.com` and the zone name itself without any prefix i.e. `newserver.example.com.`

Since you're using this only in your internal DNS you have, I think, an edge case, where you don't necessarily run into [this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/170194/why-cant-a-domains-root-be-a-cname) and can still do:

```
# zone for newserver.example.com.
@  IN CNAME newserver.cloudapp.net.
```

and don't have to do

```
# zone for newserver.example.com.
@  IN A  <the_ip-address_of_newserver.cloudapp.net.>
```

which is the alternative.

Comment: Psst. I know this is an old answer, but you've got an apex CNAME in there...