# How to redirect root domain to www using Openshift v2 and nginx?

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, openshift-origin

I am not able redirect my *example.com* request to *www.example.com* and they are now both different websites, pointing to the same application.

### Background:

I have installed php 7 with nginx on Openshift ver. 2 using [this](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/253-php-7). I have added 2 aliases for the application deployed, as follows:

1. Application URL: myapp.rhcloud.com; 
   Domain Name: www.example.com
2. Application URL: myapp.rhcloud.com; 
   Domain Name: example.com

I have also added the following DNS detailes in CNAME:

1. Name:   www.example.com;    Value:  myapp.rhcloud.com
2. Name:   @;  Value:  www.example.com

My nginx config file (erb) is as follows:

```
server {
    root              <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/www;
    listen            <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_PORT'] %>;
    server_name       <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'] %>;
    index             index.php index.html index.htm <%= ENV['NGINX_EXTRA_INDEX'] %>;
    set_real_ip_from  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP'] %>;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

which becomes:

```
server {
    root              /path/to/my/app-root/folder/;
    listen            127.11.2.1:8080;
    server_name       myapp.rhcloud.com;
    index             index.php index.html index.htm ;
    set_real_ip_from  127.11.2.1;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

I have tried to add another server block in my nginx config file like the following:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

However I am not sure what should I use in place of example.com.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Openshift but it seems to me that there is something wrong in your DNS settings where you've created a CNAME for your root domain:

> Name: @; Value: www.example.com

According to DNS specifications you cannot create CNAME record for your root domain. Even if your DNS server allow you to do that, it will not work.

Check out [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/170194/why-cant-a-domains-root-be-a-cname) to see why is that not allowed.

Comment: I was not sure about the CNAME for root domain, as well. However, I just gave it a try. But, as you can I can not use A name, also, since the IP address is not static (`<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_PORT'] %>`)

Comment: In that case, you need a third party with some advanced DNS server to let you CNAME your root domain. I myself am part of a team to create frfra.com projct that does that for free, But it is not completed yet, You can use cloudflare.com

Answer (score 0):

As far as DNS goes, as pointed out by another answer, you cannot do `@ CNAME www`, i.e., cannot point from the root to a subdomain.  However, doing the opposite, `www CNAME @`, i.e., pointing from a subdomain back to the root, should be entirely acceptable, and does not have to be symmetric to the way the web-side of the domain is represented (e.g., web-site-wise, you could still point from root to a subdomain, even though you're doing the exact opposite on the DNS side).

As far as the web-site way is concerned, it would seem that it would make sense to have both `server` definitions in the same file, where you simply manually prefix `www.` right in front of `<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'] %>` for one of the servers, e.g., `server_name www.<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'] %>;`.

Alternatively, although it wouldn't be the most efficient solution, you could also do a conditional redirect with an `if` statement in a single `server` context (e.g., one with `server_name .example.com;`):

```
if ($host != "www.example.com") {
    rewrite ^   http://www.example.com$request_uri? redirect;
}
```

Alternatively, if you would rather prefer pretty but less efficient code, you could also use the regular expressions:

```
if ($host !~ "^www\.") {
    rewrite ^   http://www.$host$request_uri?   redirect;
}
```

Comment: I **can not** _simply_ add a 'www.' prefix at '<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'] %>', since it points to the sub-domain of 'rhcliud.com'; whereas I need to redirect 'example.com' to 'www.example.com' which are mapped through aliases at Openshift console. The same applies for you second option, too.

Comment: @thelastray, maybe it shouldn't point to a subdomain, then?  I'm not too sure that I follow your need to use OpenShift templates, especially if they apparently don't let you handle aliases correctly?  Why not simply hardcode the values within the nginx file instead of creating a plethora of templates?

Comment: `@cnst`I am afraid. I am not a web server guy. Could you please explain how can I hardcode the values in nginx config.

Comment: @thelastray It sounds like you may not be aware that you can have multiple server declarations in a single file.  Basically, just define a whole separate (and hardcoded) `server` right next to your original one, in the same file, without using any of your template variables, if none have the useful data in them.

Comment: `@cnst` Yes, I have tried adding a separate server block in my config as above in my original question. But this gives **503 service temporarily unavailable**

Comment: @thelastray, who gives you that error?  That's not generally an nginx error.

Comment: `@cnst' When I am trying to access my website, with that extra server block in my config file. Actually that error is from Openshift Apache server because of wrong configuration, I believe.

Comment: nginx lets you have as many servers as you require in a single file; indeed, the problem seems unrelated to nginx

Comment: No, this not a problem of nginx, in particular. Rather it is perhaps more related to openshift configuration and domain forwarding things.