# How to configure S3 or DNS to handle incomplete name (sans www) for web site?

Tags: domain-name-system, website, amazon-s3, cname-record

I have a set up a bucket called "www.mydomainname.com" to host my website and I have configured the CNAME such that "www.mydomainname.com" points to the my endopint http://www.mydomainname.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

It works and when people who type the the full url "www.mydomainname.com" are able to see my index page

But most people are in the habit of typing incoplete domain name -- they just type "mydomainname.com" and their browser fails to find my site.

Is there a way to configure CName or S3 bucket such that typing "mydomainname.com" take them to my s3 website ?
(I am using Networksolutions as my DNS provider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just add a CNAME for `mydomainname.com` pointing to `www.mydomainname.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.`

Comment: This question has a more comprehensive discussion: http://serverfault.com/questions/62527/how-to-create-a-cname-for-a-domains-root-name