# Safe to point www to root/naked domain on Azure?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record

My client would like to use the root/naked domain name of his site, rather than the www subdomain. I am not overly savvy on the fine points on DNS.
Is it safe to create a CNAME record that points the www subdomain to the root?
i.e. http://www.example.com --> http://example.com
I have seen examples redirecting TO the www, but not the reverse.

If it matters, the site is on Azure, and DNS settings are hosted at dreamhost.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CNAME`s from root to a subdomain are [not good](https://serverfault.com/questions/274106/is-there-any-way-to-point-the-root-domain-to-a-cname), but the reverse seems harmless.  You can create a CNAME for `www` as you described and DNS should be ok.  But now I can hit your site as `example.com` or `www.example.com`.  This may not be as neat as your client desires.  A better solution would be to create an `A` record for `www` which points at a [redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) server which will bounce the users to the naked domain.

Comment: this a good answer but I wonder if it's still relevant in 2023 with Azure Front Door and others