# Top level domain with dynamic IP

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have a web server at home. I bought a top level domain `mydomain.com` and I want it to point to my server. I also have a duckdns domain `mydomain.duckdns.org`. They say in their faq:

> Q: I want to use my own Domain name with DuckDNS, can I do this?
>
> A: Yes you can. At your NAME provider set your purchased record as a
>   CNAME to your duckdns.org record. www.ilikeweasels.org CNAME
>   weasels.duckdns.org

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. If there is an `A` record then it doesn't allow me to setup a `CNAME`. Then if I delete the `A` and have the `CNAME` only, then it I get this:

> M-PRIF -E- [mydomain.com] Cannot get domain data (-nameserverIP-
>   -nameservername-)

**UPDATE**: So I could manage to set it up for `www.mydomain.com`, but not for `mydomain.com`.

**UPDATE2**: I've just read this one [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain?rq=1) and It seems I shouldn't create a `CNAME` record for the root domain. So the question here is whether there is any workaround?

Comment: [I would not recommend DuckDNS to anyone.](http://serverfault.com/a/713737/152073)

Comment: @AndrewB And what would you recommend?

Comment: Just a note on terminology: `mydomain.com` is not a *top-level domain* (`com`, on the other hand, is an example of a tld). Also *the root domain* sounds like it refers to the actual root (aka `.`), particularly written with definite article like that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround.
I left the root `A` record and created a `CNAME` for `www.mydomain.com`. Then with `HTTP 301` all requests going to `mydomain.com` have been redirected to `www.mydomain.com` which then points to `mydomain.duckdns.org` and finally my webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and would like to leave my solution here for future travelers:

I created two DNS entries. One `CNAME` that maps all sub domains `*.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.duckdns.org`. And one `ALIAS` that points `mydomain.com` to `mydomain.duckdns.org`.

Then on my local server I'm using a reverse proxy to handle some sub domains but that is just optionally.

Answer (score -1):

The physical address is designated by the **A** record which a **CNAME** would refer to, so it's strange that you are not able to set up a CNAME.

Are you maybe reversing the order? I.E. putting the CNAME where the original host name should be or vice versa?

***EDIT:*** I just saw your edit, did this solve your issue? Regardless you should most definitely be able to set up a CNAME as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: No, I'm still unable to get `mydomain.com` to point to my server.

Comment: Best of luck, my apologies for jumping in without much of answer. Here are some links I found. [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/274106/is-there-any-way-to-point-the-root-domain-to-a-cname) and [here](http://mrooney.github.io/blog/2012/05/01/dns-root-slash-apex-cnames-in-practice/)