# How to point 1and1 domain to no-ip hostname

Tags: linux, nginx, virtualhost, dynamic-dns, 1and1

I have a linux server hosting several virtual domains using Nginx.  My ISP provides a dynamic IP and I am trying to avoid paying extra for a static IP.  I am experimenting with a domain name purchased from 1and1.  If I enter my server's current IP address as the A-record of the 1and1 domain everything works fine (but of course I would have to manually update the A-record when my ISP changes my IP address which is unexceptable.)  I created a hostname with no-ip which automatically updates my IP adress.  If I configure my 1and1 domain to use a frame redirect to my no-ip hostname I lose my domain name somewhere so that the browser shows my server's generic welcome page instead of the virtual domain index page.

So, my question is, How do I direct my 1and1 domain name to my server such that the request is directed to the appropriate virtual domain on my server while at the same time having my IP address automatically (and hopefully, instantly) updated?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `CNAME` instead of a `A` record pointing to the no-ip FQDN.

The updates will probably not be instant, at least in my experience it will take a few minutes for the local client to figure out that the IP has changed and submits the update to the dyndns provider.

Comment: note that this will work for "www.example.com" but not necessarily for "example.com" as you technically can't have a CNAME on the root domain. some dns providers still allow this but it can lead to all sorts of problems (like slave zones not updating anymore). http://serverfault.com/questions/55528/set-root-domain-record-to-be-a-cname

Comment: I created the CNAME as my no-ip hostname.  1and1 said updates will take 24-48 hours.  Thank you for your advice.